# Scala on Spark [filtering out duplicate rows after Self Join]

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I've tried filtering out data using python

```
|name_x | age_x | salary_x | name_y | age_y | salary_y | age_diff
| James | 23    | 200000   | Jack   | 24    | 210040   |  1
| Jack  | 24    | 210040   | James  | 23    | 200000   |  1
| Irene | 25    | 200012   | John   | 25    | 210000   |  0
| Johny | 26    | 21090    | Elon   | 29    | 210012   |  3
| Josh  | 24    | 21090    | David  | 23    | 213012   |  1
| John  | 25    | 210000   | Irene  | 25    | 200012   |  0
```

**row1** and **row2** are duplicates also 
**row3** and **row6** are duplicates as 
 **name_x** == **name_y**,  **age_x** == **age_y**,  **salary_x** == **salary_y** 
 and Not considering the **age_diff** which is the **Output**.
  I need to filter them out, [one of the duplicate row].

Need the final output to be.: as below filtering out duplicates

```
|name_x | age_x | salary_x | name_y | age_y | salary_y | age_diff
| James | 23    | 200000   | Jack   | 24    | 210040   |  1
| Irene | 25    | 200012   | John   | 25    | 210000   |  0
| Johny | 26    | 21090    | Elon   | 29    | 210012   |  3
| Josh  | 24    | 21090    | David  | 23    | 213012   |  1
```

On python have implemented as below which returns the index of the duplicates, and also which is too slow.

```
def duplicate_index(df):
    length = len(df.columns) - 1 # -1 for removing the time difference
    length = length//2
    nrows = df.shape[0]
    duplicate_index = [] 
    for row in range(nrows-1):
        count  = 0
        for frow in range(row+1,nrows):
            if (list(df.iloc[row][:length]) == list(df.iloc[frow][length:-1])):
                if (list(df.iloc[row][length:-1]) == list(df.iloc[frow][:length])):
                    duplicate_index.append(frow)
                    #print(row, frow)
                    count = count + 1
            if count == 1:
                break
    return duplicate_index
del_index = duplicate_index(df)
final_df  = df.drop(index = del_index)
```

But now i had to do these on Scala using spark, is there, any faster way of approaching these filter, or something like a **shift** in python. or **window** on scala

Comment: can you show how the original dataframe is made?

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala  val df = sparkSession.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv").option("header", true).option("inferSchema",true).csv(path+"data.csv")

Comment: the question says you used a self join..can you show that statement?

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala val df_Id = dff.join(dff, Seq("ID"), "inner")

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala plus still need to self join with two other keys of same df. so three dataframes are created, and them changing the column name, merge them. that is how the dataframe is created.

Comment: Nice salaries.  If I answer the question can I come work for your company? :)

Comment: @Jeremy yes Jeremy i would like too, I wish I had my own company., To make some big decisions (^_^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think astro_asz's answer is the cleaner approach, but for completeness, here is how to do it using a window:

EDIT: I changed the dataset so two people had the same name and added a unique ID based on the contents of each row

```
val people = Seq(
  ("1", "James", 23, 200000),
  ("1", "James", 24, 210040),  // two people with same name
  ("2", "Irene", 25, 200012),
  ("2", "John",  25, 210000),
  ("3", "Johny", 26,  21090),
  ("3", "Elon",  29, 200000),
  ("4", "Josh",  24, 200000),
  ("4", "David", 23, 200000))

val columns = Seq("ID", "name", "age", "salary")
val df = people.toDF(columns:_*)

// In general you want to use the primary key from the underlying data store
// as your unique keys.  If for some weird reason the primary key is not 
// available or does not exist, you can try to create your own.  This
// is fraught with danger.  If you are willing to make the (dangerous)
// assumption a unique row is enough to uniquely identify the entity in
// that row, you can use a md5 hash of the contents of the row to create
// your id
val withKey = df.withColumn("key", md5(concat(columns.map(c => col(c)):_*)))

val x = withKey.toDF(withKey.columns.map(c => if (c == "ID") c else "x_" + c):_*)
val y = withKey.toDF(withKey.columns.map(c => if (c == "ID") c else "y_" + c):_*)

val partition = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("x_key")
val df2 = x.join(y, Seq("ID"))
  .where('x_key =!= 'y_key)
  .withColumn("rank", rank over partition)
  .where('rank === 1)
  .drop("rank", "x_key", "y_key")

df2.show
/*-+------+-----+--------+------+-----+--------+                         
|ID|x_name|x_age|x_salary|y_name|y_age|y_salary|
+--+------+-----+--------+------+-----+--------+
| 3|  Elon|   29|  200000| Johny|   26|   21090|
| 1| James|   24|  210040| James|   23|  200000|
| 4| David|   23|  200000|  Josh|   24|  200000|
| 2| Irene|   25|  200012|  John|   25|  210000|
+--+------+-----+--------+------+-----+-------*/
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add additional condition to the join that keeps only one of the two rows, for example name_x < name_y. Here is an example:

Example data frame:

```
  val rowsRdd: RDD[Row] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
    Seq(
      Row(1, "James",  1, 10),
      Row(1, "Jack",   2, 20),
      Row(2, "Tom",    3, 30),
      Row(2, "Eva",    4, 40)
    )
  )

  val schema: StructType = new StructType()
    .add(StructField("id",      IntegerType,  false))
    .add(StructField("name",    StringType,  false))
    .add(StructField("age",     IntegerType, false))
    .add(StructField("salary",  IntegerType, false))

  val df0: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowsRdd, schema)

  df0.sort("id").show()
```

Which gives:

```
+---+-----+---+------+
| id| name|age|salary|
+---+-----+---+------+
|  1|James|  1|    10|
|  1| Jack|  2|    20|
|  2|  Eva|  4|    40|
|  2|  Tom|  3|    30|
+---+-----+---+------+
```

Rename columns of the dataframe:

```
val df1 = df0.columns.foldLeft(df0)((acc, x) => acc.withColumnRenamed(x, x+"_x"))
val df2 = df0.columns.foldLeft(df0)((acc, x) => acc.withColumnRenamed(x, x+"_y"))
```

Then make a join with three conditions:

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2,
    col("id_x") === col("id_y") and
    col("name_x") =!= col("name_y") and
    col("name_x") < col("name_y"),
    "inner")
df3.show()
```

which returns

```
+----+------+-----+--------+----+------+-----+--------+                         
|id_x|name_x|age_x|salary_x|id_y|name_y|age_y|salary_y|
+----+------+-----+--------+----+------+-----+--------+
|   1|  Jack|    2|      20|   1| James|    1|      10|
|   2|   Eva|    4|      40|   2|   Tom|    3|      30|
+----+------+-----+--------+----+------+-----+--------+
```

Depending on how you define a duplicate in your data, the condition that distinguishes two duplicates would be different.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. [That is the required output] But lets say the names are same or if we have some attributes which are same, it does not work. Eg: here replace "Jack" with "James" and we get only one column. But it should return two column and remove only the row which are exactly same in attribute_x and attribute_y.

Comment: If the names aren't unique, I think you're better off coming up with a unique ID per person in the beginning and using that instead of name.  If available, the best source of a unique ID is usually the primary key from your data source.